# post per page is not working with sticky post query in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops, post, phpquery

```
this is my post loop that i am using


                  <?php
                        $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
                            rsort( $sticky );
                                $args = array(
                                'post_type'           => 'post',
                                'post__in'            => $sticky,
                                'posts_per_page'      => 1
                                );
                           $sticky_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                          while ( $sticky_query->have_posts() ) : $sticky_query->the_post();
                      ?>
                    <article class="cust-arc-post">
                      <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="">
                      <div class="arc-post-header">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
                        <a class="cat" href="javascript:;">Category Title</a>
                      </div>
                      <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 20, '...' ); ?></p>
                    </article>
                      <?php endwhile;
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                      ?>
```

i tried using `offset` but no luck,

i think something is wrong with my loop

if anyone can help me with this
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the information you need can be found in the [theme handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/sticky-posts/#show-sticky-posts)

---

As stated in the codex, this displays just the first sticky post, if none return the last post published:

```php
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post__in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Your problem likely lies in the `rsort();` function, because it's reversing the array **from highest to lowest.**

Comment: 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1

this works for me before you guys answer Thanks BTW For your Answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
<?php
    $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
    rsort( $sticky );
    $posts_per_page = 12;
    $sticky_count = count($sticky);
    
    if ($sticky_count < $posts_per_page) {
        $posts_per_page = $posts_per_page - $sticky_count;
    } else {
        $posts_per_page = 1;
    }

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post__in'       => $sticky,
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page
    );
    $sticky_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $sticky_query->have_posts() ) : $sticky_query->the_post(); ?>
        <article class="cust-arc-post">
            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="">
            <div class="arc-post-header">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
                <a class="cat" href="javascript:;">Category Title</a>
            </div>
            <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 20, '...' ); ?></p>
        </article>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```